# Maven enforce plugin ignore in tests

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a maven project that has the enforcer plugin enabled for validation phase, but i want to disable the execution of the plugin in test phase, just apply it in no tests.

Why? Because i'm using the DependencyConvergence rules and in i need to add for example jetty server which has his own implementation about servlet-api and it's needed..

Is there any way to handle it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: First why is it a problem running the maven-enforcer-plugin in test phase...what kind of rules do you use?

Comment: Sorry, question edited.

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand your problem correctly. You want to apply the dependencyConvergence rule, but not for artifacts with scope test?

Comment: No, i want ignore that plugin if i'm running tests.

Comment: Sorry to says but this does not make sense...If you dependencyConvergence fails this means your tests use something different than your production code which shouldn't be the case.